# Is there a way to notify the web app about key vault secret's updates before cache expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault

I have an asp.net core 3.1 web app running within VM and during startup I am preparing Azure Key Vault Configuration with rotation of every 5 minutes. This will pull down all the secrets from azure key vault and cached for 5 minutes.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions
                {
                    Vault = "https://testvault007.vault.azure.net/",
                    ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    Client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(new AzureServiceTokenProvider().KeyVaultTokenCallback)),
                });
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

If during cache time, 5 minutes, secrets are updates, then is there a way to notify web app about this and re-load it immediately?

Comment: You can use Topic-Subscription method, where the client which changes Key Vault will send a message to Topic that vault with `x` key is changed and their can be a subscriber which changes value of it in the cache. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: can you focus more and can provide some article on it

Comment: You can follow this documentation for sending custom events (Key Vault changes) to Event Grid - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal. Then, you can use Azure Functions for handling those messages - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-functions

Comment: Does this comment responds well to your question?

Comment: @user584018 if there was a cheap way to update the cache, there wouldn't be any need for ReloadInterval. To get notified, *your application* needs to either expose an endpoint or use (not cheap) websockets connection to the server. Needless to say, AKV or *any* server or service can't maintain websocket connections for every client. Are you sure you want that complexity? After all, when you manually change account credential for a service,  it takes far more than 5 minutes to update the configuration of client applications

Comment: You may be able to [modify the AKV config provider](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/extensions/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets/src/AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.cs) to use AKV events, although it's not straightforward. It seems AKV events are only sent to Azure Event Grid, which makes perfect sense from a scaleability perspective. After that, the problem is getting the notification to your app. Using an Azure function wouldn't help - it's your app that needs the notification!

Comment: One way would be to expose an endpoint from your app and [have Event Grid post to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events). That endpoint would have to call your custom provider and tell it to reload its cache.

Comment: Similar to this is exposing a webhook in your app [and having Event Grid post to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery).

Comment: A nice option that wouldn't require endpoints would be to use Azure SignalR. Unfortunately, Event Grid doesn't publish to SignalR directly. You'd have to use an Azure Function to receive the event, forward it to SignalR and have your custom provider listen for such notifications. You avoid the local webhook but now you need two extra Azure services. [This article describes how to do all this](https://dev.to/davidgsola/a-real-time-event-grid-viewer-with-serverless-signalr-35ke)

Comment: So once again, does the 5' delay with occasional failures really justify this complexity?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos. Thanks for your all suggestion. somehow I handled 5 minutes failure and I don't need such a complexity. But awesome useful information. Appreciate and thanks a lot

Comment: I didn't know about AKV events until I started investigating this, but I do know that polling is cheap and server-side notifications aren't. The rest I posted as I searched docs, blogs etc. I know Azure SignalR exists so I looked for a link between AKV and SignalR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but is it worth it? Polling is cheap while listening for notifications is complex. After all, we have to handle far longer delays when a system's credentials change before all client applications receive the new credentials.

The code for the AKV provider is [available on Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/extensions/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets/src/AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.cs) and could be modified to handle notifications. The problem is getting the notification from AKV to the provider.

If there was a cheap way to update the cache, there wouldn't be any need for ReloadInterval. To get notified, your application needs to either expose an endpoint (a plain HTTP endpoint or a webhook) or use websockets connection to the server, which aren't cheap when talking about cloud scale. Needless to say, AKV or any server or service can't maintain websocket connections for every client.

It seems AKV events are [only sent to Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-overview), which makes perfect sense from Azure's scaleability perspective. This makes listening to notifications harder for web apps that aren't hosted on Azure though.

With Event Grid a given, the problem is getting the notification to your app.

- One way would be to expose an endpoint from your app and [have Event Grid post to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events). That endpoint would have to call your custom provider and tell it to reload its cache.
- Similar to this is exposing a webhook in your app and [having Event Grid post to the webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery). In both cases you need to expose an endpoint to the public internet, protect it, handle firewalls, domain names etc.
- A nice option that wouldn't require endpoints would be to use Azure SignalR. Unfortunately, Event Grid doesn't publish to SignalR directly. You'd have to use an Azure Function to receive the event, forward it to SignalR and have your custom provider listen for such notifications. You avoid the local webhook but now you need two extra Azure services. [This article explains how to do all this](https://dev.to/davidgsola/a-real-time-event-grid-viewer-with-serverless-signalr-35ke)

All this adds cost, complexity and extra maintenance and monitoring work. The overall solution would be less reliable as it's vulnerable to outages in Event Grid, Azure Functions or SignalR.

Is a 5 minute delay worth it?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos! Thanks a lot. Appreciate!